# If this question is off-topic, where is it on-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, off-topic

This question:

[Google Calendar alternative for an NGO who wishes to publicly share an activities calendar](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127824/google-calendar-alternative-for-an-ngo-who-wishes-to-publicly-share-an-activitie)

which is somewhere in the convex hull of SF, SR, SU and maybe WebApps, has been closed as off-topic. So, first, I think it kind of fits the site scope. But - if it doesn't - which site is it a better fit for?

Note that I'm not asking for a software product, I'm asking about what an organization might do instead of having a Google calendar and sharing it publicly.

Answer (score 2):

It was closed as being a "shopping question":

> Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the So become obsolete quickly.

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is probably your best bet.